# handling LinearLayout within a ScrollView

Tags: android

Originally, I had LinearLayout>ScrollView>TableLayout and the code below:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.photos_layout, null);
setContentView(layout);
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//get the tableLayout which we created in main.xml
tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    //Create a new row to be added.
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    //Create text views to be added to the row.
    TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    //Put the data into the text view by passing it to a user defined function createView()
    createView(tr, tv1, Integer.toString(i+1));
    createView(tr, tv2, names[i]);
    //Add the new row to our tableLayout tl
    tl.addView(tr);
}
```

The problem is that a scrollView can only have one child, so if I wanted to add more views in addition to the tableLayout I can't. In order to overcome this problem I made the hierarchy like LinearLayout>ScrollView>linearLayout>tableLayout. However, now the code above crashes the app.

What do I need to change in order to populate my table, as well as add views to my newly created linearlayout?

Comment: If you have crashes, you should include the LogCat output here

Comment: post the crash log. and some xmls?

Comment: First off, post the stacktrace of the crash. Secondly, why not just create the entire layout completely in xml or completely programmatically? If you're gonna do it programmatically, you should define layout params for adding the views to their parents. Also, the scrollview can only have one DIRECT child. So you can place whatever you want inside the linearlayout which is inside the scrollview. Also, can I ask what exactly you are trying to accomplish? You are probably making your view way too complicated...

Comment: well right now it's just a test app to get to know android. I have my activity and I want to put the tablelayout and some buttons in it. It's going to be larger than the screen so I placed it inside a scrollView. But I think i'll take your advice and do it all programatiically; I hate figuring out how to connect the layout and the code.

Comment: @Adam post the log. We can't help you without that. Also, you probably just want a GridView or something like that.

Comment: I basically want ios' tableView capabilities... having large rows with images and other content inside the rows

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest removing the parent LinearLayout. Scrollview in itself can be the parent, and then have one LinearLayout as its only direct child.

In the code you posted that you mentioned was crashing, you're not adding any view to your "newly-created" LinearLayout, instead you're adding a new row to your TableLayout, which if I guess correctly, is inside your scrollview. This is perfectly ok and should not be the cause of the crash.